# how to keep my background service active when android system kills my app?

Tags: android, service, background-service, termination

I have a background service which runs in background to track screen on and off events. its started as below :

```
Intent intentService = new Intent(context, UnlockdService.class);
context.startService(intentService);
```

And it is returning `Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT` in the method onStartCommand. But still when android system kills app this thread dies as well.

How can I prevent it?

Comment: There is no way you can assure that a service won't be killed.  The best you can do is make sure you're restarted when possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was so simple: Returning `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()` did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a better solution to have a BroadcastReceiver instead of a Service. In your onReceive, you could then start your service to do its work, and then the service could self terminate - maybe you could use an IntentService if your work is one shot.

If you still want a Service, you can make it less likely to be killed by having a permanent notification in the notification bar, but that can be bad from a user perspective. I strongly recommend going the broadcast receiver route.

Comment: Such a stupid issue.. solution was so simple... START_STICKY did the job :D